# Non-blocking state update

Tags: javascript, performance, svelte

there! I was wondering if Svelte has a way to update state in a non-blocking fashion.
Here's artifically slow tabs example. https://svelte.dev/repl/565c333f0ab141c1a97e96f855d2e7d0?version=4.2.12

As you can see, when you switch Tab 2, it prevents tab button from being active until tab content rendering finishes.
It makes the UI feel less snappy.

I was seeking something like useTransition in React: https://react.dev/reference/react/useTransition#marking-a-state-update-as-a-non-blocking-transition

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your real use-case, what makes Tab 2 so slow to load? In your example, I would say the problem is that you show too much content at the same time, and the solution is to use pagination to only show parts of it at the same time, and then it would never be slow. A similar solution doesn't work for your actual case?

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the slow part in an `#await` that defers to the next event loop, which causes the contents to be rendered separately (though still in one chunk).

```html
{#await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r)) then}
  <!-- slow contents here -->
{/await}
```